# Data Binding Generated List to WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've developed a method to generate a list of items to be displayed on my WPF DataGrid. The list is populated with the data that I want, but I cannot figure out how to display it on my DataGrid. This is my first time using a custom data source. I've read the docs for Data Binding & Data Context but I haven't found anything that helped me solve my issue. Here is the error I'm receiving:

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Type' property not found on 'object' ''Char' (HashCode=7536755)'. BindingExpression:Path=Type; DataItem='Char' (HashCode=7536755); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

I can't tell if this is a pathing error or data conversion. I don't think it's a datatype issue and they're all string in text columns. So I've messed around with my XAML to try and fix the pathing. Leaving me with :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="resourcesGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source= resourceList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="215" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" Margin="30,57,0,0" FontSize="8" AutoGenerateColumns="False" MinColumnWidth="15" MaxColumnWidth="70">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="resourceCheck"  Binding="{Binding Path=Check}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="resourceName"  Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="6" Header="Resource Name" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="80"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="resourceEmail"  Binding="{Binding Path=Email}" FontSize="6" Header="Email" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="80"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="resourceType"  Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" FontSize="6" Header="Resource Type" HeaderStringFormat="" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Method to Populate List:

```
public List<Resources> PopulateResourceList(string path)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))  // open file
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))   // read the stream with TextReader
        {
            string line;
            string rname = String.Empty;
            string remail = String.Empty;
            string rtype = String.Empty;
            List<Resources> items = new List<Resources>();

            reader.ReadLine();
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] elements = line.Split(',');

                rname = elements[1];
                remail = elements[3];
                //needs changed. add type to table and populate it
                rtype = String.Empty;

                Resources resource = new Resources
                {
                    Check = false,
                    Name = rname,
                    Email = remail,
                    Type = rtype
                };

                items.Add(resource);

            }
            //resourceGrid.ItemsSource = items;
            return items;
        }
    }
```

resourceList Initialization:

```
    List<Resources> resourceList;
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        availGrid_Headers();
        resourceList = PopulateResourceList(Paths.resourcePath);
        //resourceGrid.ItemsSource = PopulateResourceList(Paths.resourcePath);
    }
```

I've tried several different approaches on the Bindings and ItemsSource in XAML. I also added the line: "this.DataContext=this;" to the cs so that it would reference the code that I have in cs. This is my first time binding to my own data source, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-Dan

Comment: A string is an array of char. Show us all the code required to reproduce your issue. I suspect you end up with a string for  itemssource.

Comment: How and where have you defined "resourceList"? Initialisation of resourceList too?. Usually this error occurs when binding path u defined does not exists in the datasource.

Comment: I'll update it with the list initialization and method to populate list

Comment: You need a public property to bind. ResourceList cannot be bound because it's a private variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Itemsource property is bound to resourceList Property defined in code behind i assume. It should be used as path for Itemsource. In your current XAML, Itemsource source markup extension is set to a string "resourceList" rather than an property "resourceList". Change the itemsource to like this

```
<DataGrid x:Name="resourcesGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=resourceList}"
```

Also u have set the datacontext to instance "this", Hence the source property of itemsource is inherited to the datacontext, so "resourcelist" collection be the path in the datacontext for source of data. Make the resourcelist a property public to be visible for binding.

Comment: I made the list public, changed source to path and tried with this.DataContext=this commented/uncommented. Previously it displayed the grid with no data, now there is neither.

Comment: Have you made the list into a property. Something like this public List<Resources> resourceList {get;set;}. Check out output window if any errors are there. Set the datacontext to this.